# Laravel 5.4 Disable Register Route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am trying to disable the register route on my application which is running in Laravel 5.4.

In my routes file, I have only the

```
Auth::routes();
```

Is there any way to disable the register routes?

Comment: In current laravel version 5.7.5 there's is option for this. `Auth::routes(['register' => false]);`

Comment: see https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L1152

Answer (score 95, accepted):

The `code`:

```php
Auth::routes();
```

its a shorcut for this collection of routes:

```php
// Authentication Routes...
Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

// Registration Routes...
Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

// Password Reset Routes...
Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

So you can substitute the first with the list of routes and comment out any route you don't want in your application.

**Edit for `laravel version => 5.7`**

In newer versions you can add a parameter to the `Auth::routes()` function call to disable the register routes:

```php
Auth::routes(['register' => false]);
```

The email verification routes were added:

```php
Route::get('email/verify', 'Auth\VerificationController@show')->name('verification.notice');
Route::get('email/verify/{id}', 'Auth\VerificationController@verify')->name('verification.verify');
Route::get('email/resend', 'Auth\VerificationController@resend')->name('verification.resend');
```

BTW you can also disable `Password Reset` and `Email Verification` routes:

```php
Auth::routes(['reset' => false, 'verify' => false]);
```

Comment: why to write this whole section of every auth route, when you can just simply do as `Auth::routes(['register' => false]);`, why?

Comment: @Haritsinh. The question was about laravel version **5.4**. In **5.4** version the `Auth::routes()` function does not accept any argument, that was introduced only in more recent versions.

Comment: ok, you are right my friend, `Auth::routes()` supports argument after laravel **5.7** but you can also do like this in laravel version < **5.7** `Route::redirect('register', 'login', 301);` which looks simple than above isn't it?

Comment: @Haritsinh I want to point that this question is tagged and explicity asked for Laravel 5.4. In version 5.4 the function `Route::redirect()` did not exist.

Comment: ok, @dparoli it's my fault, i have not seen that, `redirect` also added in `laravel 5.5`, sorry thanks for clearing.

Answer (score 37):

Since Laravel 5.7, a new `$options` parameter is introduced to the [`Auth::routes()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php#L1147) method; through which you can pass an array to control the generation of the *required* routes for user-authentication (valid entries can be chosen from the `'register'`, `'reset'`, or `'verify'` string literals).

```
Auth::routes(['register' => false]);
```

Comment: The other option is to add email verification routes, which are disabled by default. `Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);`

Comment: This should be the answer as it is the best [practice] way to do it if you only want to disable the register route without wanting to edit the other default Auth routes.

Comment: This should be considered as the perfect answer, as this is the proper way to ignore the register routes and works with Laravel 5.8 also.

Answer (score 23):

You could try this.

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'register', function(){
    return redirect('/');
});
```

Add those routes just below the `Auth::routes()` to override the default registration routes. Any request to the `/register` route will redirect to the baseUrl.

Comment: Disables `/login` page.

Comment: Works really well. Simple solution! Thanks!

Comment: Quite Simple Solution and Efficiently Worked.

Comment: @Jason false. I tested it with laravel 8 using larave ui auth bootstrap

Answer (score 7):

This is deceptively easy! You just need to override two methods in your `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php` Class. See below which will prevent the form from being displayed and most importantly block direct POST requests to your application for registrations..

```
/**
 * Show the application registration form.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function showRegistrationForm()
{
    return redirect('login');
}

/**
 * Handle a registration request for the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function register(Request $request)
{
    abort(404);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In web.php, Replace

`Auth::routes();`

With

`Auth::routes(['register' => false]);`

So that you can remove register route from default auth route list. i tried in 5.7 and it worked fine.

Comment: When I did this it also disabled my login page?

Answer (score 3):

Though the above solutions work but, I think changing the `middleware` to `'auth'` in the `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController` will be one of the easiest solutions. This will redirect all visitors to login page if they want to access any of the registration routes. Like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
```

Comment: This will redirect user to the login page. And if user enters correct email/password there. He will still be redirected to the Registration page, which is incorrect as per OP's requirement.

Answer (score 3):

On my Laravel **5.6** project this method didn't work:

```php
Auth::routes(['register' => false]);
```

So I had to use the following method:

```php
Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'register', function () {
    return abort(403, 'Forbidden');
})->name('register');
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you want to restrict access to some pages for guests and only the admin can register a guest. You can achieve it by adding your own middleware on kernel.php file like below:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
      'authenticated' => \App\Http\Middleware\AuthenticatedMiddleware::class
];
```

After creating the middleware you have to use it so you can go on web.php file where your routes are and add it to the route you want to restrict like below:

```
Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register')->middleware('authenticated');
Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register')->middleware('authenticated');
```

This way registration is restricted to guests but the admin can still access the page if he ever want to register some other admin!

Don't forget to replace the `Auth::routes();` with the detailed list as below:

```
// Authentication Routes...
Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

// Registration Routes...
Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register')->middleware('authenticated');
Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register')->middleware('authenticated');

// Password Reset Routes...
Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

Comment: The Auth::routes() is in the the file routes/web.php

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can do it like this, in your web.php file:

```
Route::redirect('register', 'login', 301);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this two method to app\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController.php

```
public function showRegistrationForm(){
    return redirect('login');
}

public function register(){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just overwrite your auth **showRegistrationForm()** method ( place this code inside your **Auth/RegisterController** )

```php
public function showRegistrationForm(){
    return redirect()->route('login');
}
```

I'm just redirecting my register route to the login route. Here you don't need to append or remove any other code

Answer (score -4):

Yes, there is a way

```
Auth::routes();
```

Remote that route from your web.php in your routes directory.

That route is what controls registration.

Comment: downvoters this answer not entirely wrong, its only half right

Comment: If you do that, you'll disable the login method too, so this answer is wrong!

Comment: Actually, it's only half right. `Auth::routes();` is a shortcut for a collection of routes per the documentation. If you remove `Auth::routes();` then you can put in whatever routes you *actually do want* individually (such as login). I figured that went without saying, because the documentation covered that - apparently I was wrong. This answer is technically correct and right. I don't know why people still downvoting this... it's literally half of the accepted answer.

Answer (score -5):

Change to routes :

> vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Router.php

```
public function auth()
{
    // Authentication Routes...
    $this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    $this->post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
    $this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

    // Registration Routes...
    //$this->get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
    //$this->post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');

    // Password Reset Routes...
    //$this->get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
    //$this->post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
    //$this->get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
    //$this->post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
}
```

Comment: making changes to any files in vendor folder is the worst idea

Comment: This is a bad idea as the next Laravel update would override the edited file.  Thus your changes are lost.  It also makes your code hard to follow. Another developer might not think to modify this file and thus never look their for any changes.