# How to remove Laravel 5.4's default register and make admin the one does it manually

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

i want to disable normal registeration method in Laravel, because i want just administrator the one that can register and manage/edit user.
But i doesnt know how to do it and start from where.

Thanks

Edit :
I'am not just asking how to disable default register, but also how to make Admin manually regist user in Control Panel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.4 Disable Register Route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42695917/laravel-5-4-disable-register-route)

Comment: @dparoli No, im asking how to make register manually, not just disable default register route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the only way to manage what you want is to remove the

```
Auth::routes();
```

From the routes/web.php and add each routes one by one.

You have all the routes `Auth::routes()` adds here :

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php
```

in the `auth` method.

Just copy paste them all in your routes/web.php and remove the one you don't want (the GET and POST request on /register).

As for registering the users in an admin panel, there are several ways you  could do it. Here is one :

You have a bool on your user model which I would call `is_admin`.

You create a middleware `isAdminMiddleware` where you check if the user has the `is_admin` property. If he has it, you can go further, otherwise just go back to the previous page or return a 403.

In a UsersController for example, create a GET method, which returns the view containing the form for creating a new user.

In the same controller, create a POST method, which adds the new user to the database and makes proper validation.

Don't forget to protect both routes with `isAdminMiddleware` so that users can't go to that page.

Comment: Thanks, your explanation is so good, i can understand almost of it. But i have one more question, " So i just need to make a new controller and crud for regist user?". Thanks.

Comment: It depends the way you want to structure your Controllers, it's a way yes and works fine, but some people (me included) prefer Single Action Controllers (basically, you split each method into it's own controller). I guess it's more of a personal choice

Answer (score 1):

**If you really want to keep Auth::routes()** scaffolding but disable registering from outside the admin's "control panel", this is the simplest way to do it:

Simply override methods from RegistersUsers trait in your app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php class.

```
public function showRegistrationForm() {
    abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
}

public function register() {
    abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
}
```

Second simple option is to change a middleware in __construct() method of your RegisterController.php:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('guest');
}
```

to

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

or to some custom middleware, like:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('admin');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run `php artisan make:auth` to scaffold Laravel's authentication feature, a lot of things happen.

In `routes/web.php`, you will need to remove this line

```
Auth::routes();
```

This will make routes such as `/login` and `/register` inaccessible.

You can also clean up the views that you won't need in `resources/views/auth`

Finally, you would need to write your own code from your secure administration panel to register a user that will re-use the traits that Laravel already provides.

Comment: Not really, no. You can take inspiration from `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php`

Comment: Ok, so i just need to remove auth::routes();     
   
   

then i need to make a new routes for my login ?    
   
   
  
and then i need to make a new controller for register ?  
sorry, can u eli5 or step by step explanation for me? i doesnt get it at all.